# Help identifying brand of road bike frame

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Last year I bought this second-hand bike, but I was a total newbie and didn't realize that the branding was just stickers until I received it.

It's still a good bike and I'm having fun with it, but I'm thinking of selling it and upgrading to a better one. I want to give accurate information to a future buyer, but I have no idea what the frame is. The serial number on the bottom bracket is *G609700494*.

[image: bike photo]

Does it look familiar to someone?

[image: casette]

[image: chainrings]

[image: headset]

[image: shifters]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Are you saying you have reason to believe it's _not_ a Trek?  The serial number is very seldom of any use; what are the components on it?  Can you include close-ups of the rear cluster, the cranks/chainrings, the stem and the shifters?  Did the person you bought it from tell you how old it was?

Comment: @DavidW I haven't been able to find an aluminum Trek with a curved steel fork that doesn't date back to the days of downtube shifters and quill stems, like this: https://cocosvariety.com/products/trek-1000-aluminum-road-bike  Nor any paint scheme anything like the one here.  IMO, this bike looks a lot like a generic AL frameset with a steel fork, maybe one designed 2015ish?  ISTR some online sites selling completely unbranded framesets a few years back, too.  Not a bad bike by any means, and it looks well taken care of, at least.

Comment: You could peel off the T in TREK and put it after the K, making it "REKT"

Comment: Being honest about the unknown make of the frame is also accurate information and transparent enough if you are planning to sell it. If the bike doesn't weigh 10+ kilograms  due to a very heavy frame, it'll probably be in the range of comparable 10-speed road bikes from the 2000s, a plus is that yours looks to be in good condition and has a 105 groupset. That being said, a new Trek Domane (even though it only has 8-speed Claris) will sell for 999$, so think twice if you want to give up a perfectly fine backup/winter/trainer bike for a fraction of that.

Comment: Hello, I added some pictures. The shifters are Shimano Ultegra ST-6600, they look pretty banged up, but they work great. I didn't ask how old it was, I believe the frame was new because it had zero scratches. So it appears to really be something generic. It weighs about 10kg. @DoNuT, I bought it for about 250$, so you're probably right, I haven't looked at other bikes yet.

Comment: @VasilKalchev I think the rear mech says 105, so it is a bit mix and match of components which is even more indicative that this is just a custom build. However, its not a bad bike and imo worth the 250$ if you didn't have to fix anything to get it going, a quick ebay research also shows similar bikes in that range.

Comment: @VasilKalchev One more observation: The Trek stickers on pretty much all their models I was able to google up are significantly bigger than on your bike, their name usually covers the full downtube width and is often off-center, yours is smaller and pretty much centered.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. I guess it's something generic, I'll change the stickers to something generic too.

Comment: @VasilKalchev Most likely generic, you can check these [pictures](https://99spokes.com/en-EU/bikes?brakeKind=rim&category=road&frameMaterial=aluminum&q=trek&subcategory=race%2Cendurance) for any matching bikes but it looks too generic, almost all of their road bikes have some characteristic tube shapes but yours are pretty straight and the fork also looks odd, plus the wheels are probably some replacements, too. Maybe some unbranded frame, maybe repainted but unlikely a complete Trek.